# Is there a method on Date() object to eliminate daytime saving?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, methods, momentjs

Guys I live in a country that my time zone is GMT+1

But when i

> console.log(Date());

(it's supposed to give instant time in your local machine)

Javascript assume that I use daytime saving even if my machine isn't, so the output will automatically be GMT+2

My goal is to get the time right.

I tried moment library but it gives the same output.

Sub question: where javascript takes its time data ?

Comment: JavaScript renders out times in your local time-zone, so if that isn't set correctly you may get incorrect times. Your time-zone dictates if DST is relevant or not. It's worth checking your operating system's specific settings.

Comment: Also, the way to turn on/off DST is by setting the timezone. Where there is DST, there is typically one regular timezone and one DS timezone

Comment: @tadman yep that's helped me, I was on a GMT+1  time-zone that uses day time saving, (it was turned off on my system) so my clock gives me a GMT +1 time, when javascript uses just the region so he assumed it's GMT+2. Thanks

Comment: @ControlAltDel same thing thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you create a date object with `Date()`, the value of the date is always stored in UTC.

Only the printed output changes, based on your computer's local time zone.

However, the `Date.prototype.toLocaleSting()` method allows you to print a date in any time zone. This is not the same as changing daylight saving, but it ought to be possible to choose a time zone in the desired time.

```js
function showDates() {
  let now = new Date();
  let local = now.toLocaleString('en-US');
  let seoul = now.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'Asia/Seoul'
  });
  let moscow = now.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    timeZone: 'Europe/Moscow'
  });
  result.value = `Local Time: ${local}\n`;
  result.value += `Seoul Time: ${seoul}\n`

  result.value += `Moscow Time: ${moscow}`

}

const result = document.getElementById('result');
showDates();
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<h4>Show Dates with toLocaleString()</h4>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

[Time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).